# Ruby string mutability

Tags: ruby, string

This may be a bit of a nooby question, I have been trying to get better at ruby recently, and started reading the fantastic [The Ruby Programming Language](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516178/). Something that was mentioned is that string literals are considered mutable, so in a loop it is better to use a variable then a literal, as a new string will get instantiated at every iteration.

My question is why? At first I thought it was because of interpolation, but symbols are immutable and they support interpolation. Coming from a static background, it doesn't really make much sense to me.

EDIT:

After reading [thenduks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/210/thenduks) answer, I think I may have it. AFAIK, languages like Java or C# don't have destructive string methods (they use upcase, but not upcase!). Because of things like upcase! or <<, the literal cannot be immutable.

Not 100% sure on that, the other possibility is that it is a compile-time interning that happens, which is something that just doesn't happen in a scripting language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really sure what exactly your question is, but consider the following code:

```
10.times { puts "abc".object_id }
```

This prints out 10 different id's. Why? Just because you know this string wont change doesn't mean Ruby does. If you think that `"abc"` should only be created once then what happens if you do:

```
10.times { puts "abc".upcase! }
```

The `upcase!` method mutates the string to be upper case, on the next iteration the string created in the first iteration isn't the same anymore.

Perhaps post a code example that is confusing to you?

Comment: added a bit more to the question, and gave a +1 :)